# Is there any way to login to Django admin interface using username or email?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to implement  a login system to login to Django admin via email or username. Does anyone know how to implement it. I use custom user model. I know how to allow user to  login to website using username or email. But it doesn't work in Django admin interface

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class EmailOrUsernameModelBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if '@' in username:
            kwargs = {'email': username}
        else:
            kwargs = {'username': username}
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, username):
        try:
            return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=username)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: This is quite possible. You will need to share details of what specifically doesn't work for you and the associated code for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: you need to write custom authentication backend  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends

Comment: I have written the custom authentication backend but it doesn't work in Django admin interface. When I tried to login using email it says enter your correct username and password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass request in the `authenticated` method:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class EmailOrUsernameModelBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        if '@' in username:
            kwargs = {'email__iexact': username}
        else:
            kwargs = {'username': username}
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, username):
        try:
            return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=username)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Also, make sure to put it in [**`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS):

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path.to.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend']
```

Comment: But one problem is it is case sensitive. Example@mail.com and example@mail.com are different

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom user manager sub-classing from the `UserManager` class and override the `get_by_natural_key` method.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager

class UserAccountManager(UserManager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        return self.get(
            models.Q(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
            | models.Q(**{self.model.EMAIL_FIELD: username})
        )
```

Please note that this will authenticate all users in your system by either email or password and not just on the admin page.